# How to upload projects on gitlab by user?

Tags: gitlab

We are using Gitlab (7.5.3).

I created a Repository, but I want to upload my project to it.

I've looked on the repository page for an upload button of some kind but I haven't seen anything of the sort.

I've looked at the links provided so far but I'm still getting nowhere. They mention command line, is that Windows command line ?

I am able to upload through Git GUI, how to upload without Git GUI?

And when I login to user account through putty ,it shows

```
login as: root
root@192.168.1.5's password:
Last login: Tue May 26 12:20:10 2015 from 192.168.1.12
![grep: write error]
```

Does anyone knows how we can solve these issue?

Answer (score 12):

If you have Git GUI, you probably also have Git Bash which provide command line support for git inside Windows.

You can use this Git Bash to upload your project. For this, you just need some `git` command, and you don't have to log in the Gitlab's server (I supposed it's why you tried). This command are provided by Gitlab when you create a new project and want to upload it.

First open Git Bash. Then :

```
cd c:\Users\Me\..\my_project\   # Go to your project directory in Windows
git init                        # Initialize this directory as a git repo
git remote add origin git@your_gitlab_server_ip:your_username/your_project_name.git
git push -u origin master`      # Send your code to your Gitlab instance
```

It's also a good idead to provide to git some info about you. This infos will be displayed by Gitlab :

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your_name@your_mail.com"
```

Remember that with Gitlab the only interaction between your git's repo and Gitlab should happend through the `git` command, and not with login to this server.

Comment: I have done the above steps in Git Bash. After that when i login to my gitlab server through google chrome or mozilla firefox  it shows,               502
GitLab is not responding.

Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.

Comment: When a 502 occured, try to [restart gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#starting-and-stopping) instance. Log to the Unix machine hosting gitlab and run `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`. Btw a simple `git push` can't be responsible for this. Take a look at gitlab's log in `/var/opt/gitlab` to investigate

Comment: Log to the Unix machine hosting gitlab and run sudo gitlab-ctl restart command but still it is showing 502 GitLab is not responding.Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 4 step push project to gitlab --> open command line.

```
cd to/path/local
git init
git remote add anything_name name http://scmgit.ktb/username/projectname.git
git push -u test anything_name master
```

Hope is save you day.